# jQuery setting prop("selected", true) on multi select list in Chrome only works once

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, scroll, multi-select

When trying to set a select list option to selected in order to **scroll the select list to that option**, it works in all browsers except for Chrome. In Chrome **it works once**, but successive times do not work in Chrome. How can I ensure that setting the selected attribute of an option in a select list will scroll that option into view?

Here is an example of my issue - http://jsfiddle.net/Z2rQG/

The code I am using to select an option in a list to scroll it into to view is as follows:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.scrollToOption = function (option) {
        var _option = $(option, this);
        // if option is in list
        if(_option) {
            // store the selection state
            var isSelected = _option.is(":selected");

            _option.prop("selected", true); // scroll to the option
            _option.prop("selected", isSelected);  // restore the selection state
        }
        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

**Edit:** I have also tried the [scrollTo](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo) jQuery plugin, which does not work as well in Chrome. Here is an example - http://jsfiddle.net/kavun/TW4XK/

**Edit:** Here is a clearer example of what I am trying to do. Select two options from a select list and have the list be scrolled to the last selected option. This works in all browsers except Chrome and Safari. In Chrome the first selection scrolls to the option but the second `$('#select option[value=""].prop('selected', true);` **does not scroll the list** - http://jsfiddle.net/kavun/uhnZH/

Comment: I am starting to think this is a bug with Chrome - http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=138217

Comment: Your jsfiddle doesn't contain an HTML element with the ID test, and it's very unclear what you expect it to do. Are you trying to scroll to an "element" on the page as you've suggested or an option value in the dropdown?

Comment: It does actually contain an element with the ID test, <option value="5111" id="test">5111</option>

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Browser behaviour is inconsistent with regard to which option is scrolled into view when multiple options are selected. However, selecting the option using its `selected` property plus setting the `selectedIndex` property of the `<select>` element seems to make sure the select is scrolled to the right place in all major browsers. Using this, you can get the correct vertical scrolling, select the options you want and then scroll the select manually.

Opera does not seem to fully support `scrollTop` for select elements, so this solution does not work in Opera.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uhnZH/10/

Code:

```
function selectAndScrollToOption(select, option) {
    $select = $(select);

    // Store the currently selected options
    var $selectedOptions = $select.find("option:selected");

    // Select the new option using its selected property and selectedIndex.
    // This seems to make the select scroll to the desired place in all major
    // browsers
    option.selected = true; // Required for old IE
    select.selectedIndex = option.index;

    // Measure the vertical scrolling
    var scrollTop = $select.scrollTop();

    // Re-select the original options
    $selectedOptions.prop("selected", true);

    // Scroll to the correct place
    $select.scrollTop(scrollTop);
}
```

Comment: this works as I would like, thanks. So the key is to deselect all and set selectedIndex.

Comment: Setting `selectedIndex` actually deselects all automatically, so you could drop the `$selectedOptions.prop("selected", false);` line. I'll update.

Comment: why this solution doesn't work for me? If I select a value, I can console log the right value but I see in the browser the first element...

Comment: @TakácsZsolt: Which browser?

Comment: any borwser... we could solve that problem with an other solution:

Comment: $dropdown = $('#day'); // select
    
    $y = Number($('#year').val());
    $m = Number($('#month').val());
    $d = Number($('#day').val());

    $dropdown.empty();
    for (var day = 1; day <= daysInMonth($y, $m); day++) { 
    var option = $('<option/>').val(day).text(day);
    if (day == $d){
    option = option.prop("selected",true); 
    }
    option.appendTo($dropdown);
    }

Comment: @TakácsZsolt: The jsfiddle in my answer seems to work fine. If you have an example of it not working in some other case then I'll happily take a look. As for your solution, deleting all the options and recreating them seems unnecessarily destructive to me.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is simply to scroll to a value in the dropdown, you can simply use `val` [as demonstrated in this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TW4XK/2/):

```
$('#selectList').val(51);
```

That will work in any browser.

If you're trying to scroll to an element on the page based on the value in the dropdown, you'll have to put up an example that gets us a bit closer to what you want so we can address that specific scenario.

Comment: Yes, my goal is to scroll to a value in the dropdown. Your solution works, but it deselects all other options. How could I keep all previously selected options selected?

Comment: I can save state like this, but even still the last line of code does not end up scrolling the list in Chrome - http://jsfiddle.net/kavun/gbyjK/

Comment: Tested in IE9, Firefox 15, Opera 12. Those scroll the list to the last selected value, but Chrome 22, and Safari 5 do NOT scroll the list to the last selected value.

Comment: Yep, you're right, I didn't understand that you wanted to keep the selected values and simply append a new one. @TimDown seems to have the answer to that though! :)